# unix wait command for polling

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ksh

Where I work, I have seen the below snippet in shell scripts to check for the completion of background jobs:

```
until [[ `ps -ef | grep backgroundjob | grep -v grep | wc -l` -eq 0 ]];
do
  sleep 30
done
```

Having read the man page of wait command, I know these 3 lines can be replaced by wait command in a more short and easily readable way. My questions are:

1. Are there any disadvantages or scenarios where wait command might
   not work as well as the snippet above?
2. How is wait commandimplemented? It seems to return almost
   immediately, so probably a
       tight loop? If it is a tight loop, then probably the above snippet
       which sleeps for 30 seconds would go easy on the CPU than the wait  command?

Comment: Polling on the output of `ps` is a horrible thing to do.  Invoking wc to check whether grep matched something is even worse.  If you must do this atrocity, at least change it to `while ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep -q backgroundjob; do sleep 30; done`  (And note that the `grep -v` can be easily avoided with `grep -q [b]ackgroundjob`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wait` only works for child processes of the current shell.  This means that, if your process forked to background itself, the original child process will have exited, and the shell won't be able to `wait` on it.

Some shells' `wait` builtin will return immediately if there is no such child process; others, like `bash`, will warn you:

```
$ wait 1234
bash: wait: pid 1234 is not a child of this shell
```

`wait` doesn't impose any CPU load because it uses the `waitpid(2)` system call, which pauses the process until the nominated process has exited.

Comment: Thanks. So what you are saying is, if a script named A calls (B &); and waits on it using wait, it will be able to do so if call with "A" instead of "A &"

Comment: I'm struggling to parse your question... but if a script backgrounds a process with a `&`, that process will be a child of the script and thus can be `wait`ed upon.  However, if the process forks itself because it's a daemon and always backgrounds itself, it will be detached from the shell.

Comment: I am accepting your answer. What I am not able to get is the "process forking itself" part. Could you please give an example or perhaps a link on how that is done in a shell script?

Comment: See http://www.enderunix.org/docs/eng/daemon.php for an example of how a process can fork and background itself.